# Is it possible to register a java security Provider within Android?

Tags: java, android, security, jce

Is it possible to register a `java.security.Provider` within Android OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this issue, I guess you can't:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21417

> **Query**
>
> We are developing a JCE provider and would like a way to statically register it so other apps can use it. It would also be useful if security properties can be set statically because we use them to set default algorithms and other options. In standard java both of these can be done by setting properties in the file /jre/lib/security/java.security.
>
> **Response**
>
> *I'm going to decline this at this time. Android doesn't really support sharing code this way. If some kind of shared library mechanism is added to the platform, then this could be revisited. For now, apps will have to bundle providers within themselves.*